# Benjamin-Ono-Zakharov-Kuznetsov IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

For anyone familiar with the BO-ZK model, would you please be able to help me understand this function?

The IVP for the BO-ZK equation is:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u_{t}+\mathcal{H} \partial_{x}^{2} u+u_{x y y}+u u_{x}=0, \quad(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}, t>0 \\
u(x, y, 0)=\phi(x, y)
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $u = u(x, y, t)$ is a real-valued function and H stands for the Hilbert transform.

The general Benjamin-Ono 2-dimensional equation is:
$$
u_{t}+\mathcal{H} \partial_{x}^{2} u+u u_{x}=0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0
$$

Anyways, I am specifically having trouble pinpointing **independent variable and dependent variables regarding their units and the general quantities they represent.** I am not studying a math level high enough to understand this question in its entirety, only IVP models, so I am very confused and would appreciate any and all help.

I can link the paper in the comments if anyone needs more context.
Sorry to have attached the images in links as well, I do not have the reputation points for that yet.